# Как создать клиент для сайта в Qt?

Tags: macos, qt, c++

Перед мной встала задача: необходимо создать клиент для сайта: http://ru.forvo.com. Сайт позволяет получить mp3-файл звучания иностранного слова. Я раннее никогда не сталкивался с подобной задачей, поэтому буду благодарен за любой совет. С чего начать? Как к примеру организовать поисковое поле сайта у себя в приложении? Необходимо связать виджет QTextEdit с сайтом или это как-то по другому делается?

Comment: Отдайте на аутсорс и не мучайте себя.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вопрос у вас сумбурный, создается впечатление, что вы и сами не совсем представляете, что вам нужно сделать и как, но ожидаете какого-то ответа.

Смотрите в сторону классов QHttp, QFtp, QNetworkAccessManager, QSql и им подобных.
Я бы, на вашем месте, сначала разобрался с тем, что конкретно должен позволять делать клиент, затем организовал графический интерфейс, хотя бы на листке бумаги, и уж потом только приступал к разработке. Естественно, накидав схему приложения и основные компоненты.

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно просто работать с сайтом через http протокол и комбинировать это с компонентами Qt. + проверить сайт на наличие открытого API (при помощи его с сайтом будет проще взаимодействовать).

Comment: У сайта вроде есть API. Я сделал регистрацию, получил API-ключ и не могу дальше сориентироваться. Где теперь находятся эти API?

Comment: @derkode с API так же нужно общаться с помощью http протокола. Используйте [QHttp][1] и т.п. для этих целей.

[1]:http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qhttp.html